# How to pass more arguments through tkinter bind

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I pass more arguments through tkinter's bind method?
for the example:

```
tk = Tk()
def moveShip(event,key):
    if event.keysym == 'Down' and player1.selectedCoord[1] != 9:
        if key == 'place':
            player1.selectedCoord[1] += 1
    elif event.keysym == 'Up' and player1.selectedCoord[1] != 0:
        if key == 'place':
            player1.selectedCoord[1] -= 1
    elif event.keysym == 'Left' and player1.selectedCoord[0] != 0:
        if key == 'place':
            player1.selectedCoord[0] -= 1
    elif event.keysym == 'Right' and player1.selectedCoord[0] != 9:
        if key == 'place':
            player1.selectedCoord[0] += 1

tk.bind("<Key>", command=moveShip(event,'place'))
```

instead of

```
tk.bind("<Key>", moveship)
```

when I run the first one, it says the event is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always wrap the callback function in a lambda.

```
tk.bind('<Key>', lambda event: moveShip(event, 'place'))
```

The other option is to use `partial` from `functool` to create a function with the default value of `key` already set.

```
from functools import partial

moveShip_place = partial(moveShip, key='place')

tk.bind('<Key>', moveShip_place)
```

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered (the check mark) if this solves your problem.