# How to reorder data in treeview table by alphabet by using hotkey

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I would like to create a F8 key as hotkey `GUI.bind('<F8>',reorderdata)` to reorder the row data. Sorting will focus on Name column of treeview table by the first alphabet with English (A > Z), Thai language and number. Thanks for considering my request.

follow my code below is working with clicking on heading column. but to using hotkey is not working.

[image]

```
def reorderdata(event = None):
    def treeview_sort_column(product_table, col, reverse):
        l = [(product_table.set(k, col), k) for k in product_table.get_children('')]
        l.sort(reverse=reverse)

        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
            product_table.move(k, '', index)

        product_table.heading(col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, not reverse))

    for col in header:
        product_table.heading(col, text=col,command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, False))

GUI.bind('<F8>',reorderdata)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you don't know where to start, then look for examples on the Internet about how to sort a treeview, like [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort).

Comment: I'm already done with clicking on column headings to reorder the row data but I still want to use hotkey to do it. also I have no idea to do.

Comment: `def treeview_sort_column(product_table, col, reverse):
 l = [(product_table.set(k, col), k) for k in product_table.get_children('')]
 l.sort(reverse=reverse)

 for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
  product_table.move(k, '', index)

 product_table.heading(col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, not reverse))

for col in header:
 product_table.heading(col, text=col,command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, False))

product_table.pack()`

Comment: Please don't post code like that in the comments, edit the question instead. For the hotkey, it works like any keybinding in tkinter. If you already have the sorting function, then bind it to `F8` keypress, there are examples on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679608/how-to-pass-more-arguments-through-tkinter-bind, about how to pass arguments with `bind`.